# *.xlam add-in and missing references in a new VBA project / new Excel's instance with the add-in turned on

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins, vbe

## Repro:

- Start Excel and open VBE <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
- Find *`Tools`* and click *`References`*.
- Scroll down til you find *`Microsoft Scripting Runtime`* and tick it.
- Save the file as *`Addin.xlam`* in the default location which should be something like:

  *`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns`*
- Close this Excel instance
- Start a new instance and open VBE (*you should now see the* *`Addin.xlam`* *as the second VBA Project available for the workbook. If you don't open the* *`Developer`* *tab then add-ins and tick the box next to the name to turn it on - save, close, open a new Excel instance*)
- Add a new standard Module
- Open *`References`* and you should see only 4 ticked (*default*)
- Scroll down and try to find *`Microsoft Scripting Dictionary`* - **it ain't there!?**

So, this basically means you can't add the reference to the new VBA Project  (Book1) because your *`*.xlam`* is already using it

**but**

you can't cross-use the *`Scripting`* library because trying

```
Dim d as Dictionary
```

in that newly created *`Module1`* fails as it doesn't recognise `Dictionary` object....

Is this somehow a known bug I have never realised or have I just completely overlooked something? Any workarounds?

Comment: I am unable to replicate your problem. I followed your instructions and I can add that reference to a new module in a new workbook just fine.  Did you look at the top of the list?  If you're using a reference in another open workbook or add-in it move up near the top of the list.

Comment: Even if it's not listed you should be able to just browse to scrrun.dll

Comment: @jbarker2160 gotcha! I was looking at only active references. I have about 30 other things on my list that show up before the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and I have totally missed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IDE keeps recently used references near the top of the list. ***Don't scroll down.*** It's right at the top. I'll admit. This threw me for a loop for a second too.

[image: VBAProject References]